# SSRS URL Access passing a parameter that has a dataset

Tags: ssrs-2012

I am trying to build an url to make the job of going to the SSRS page a bit faster and to eliminate all the input a user has to do (he already did it in an other program.

When I use this url:

http://localhost/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/folder/subfolder/reportname&rs:Command=Render&customerId=1000002

I can't fill out the parameter that has query where the default values of the parameters are found in the database, when i remove the query behind the parameter the textbox is filled out and the report is working as expected, i am sure the value of custimerId is in the database

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.

Data i got back from the database contained some trailing spaces. After removing those it worked like a charm.